# Popup with button, sometimes clicks are ignored

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

Found another weird `Popup` behavior: when displaying popup, there is a certain delay before controls on popup (and popup itself?) starts *working*. Namely talking about buttons clicks.

Here is a test project (to copy-paste and see).

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel x:Name="panel" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Button x:Name="button1" Width="100" Height="100"/>
        <Button x:Name="button2" Width="100" Height="100"/>
        <Popup x:Name="popup" StaysOpen="False" AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="Relative">
            <Grid x:Name="grid" Width="150" Height="150" Background="Yellow">
                <Button x:Name="button3" Width="100" Height="100"/>
            </Grid>
        </Popup>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // create timer to open popup after hovering button 1 or 2
        var timer = new Timer(500) { AutoReset = false };
        timer.Elapsed += (s, o) => Dispatcher.Invoke(() => popup.IsOpen = true);
        // button hover events
        button1.MouseMove += (s, o) => { popup.PlacementTarget = button1; timer.Start(); };
        button2.MouseMove += (s, o) => { popup.PlacementTarget = button2; timer.Start(); };
        button1.MouseLeave += (s, o) => { timer.Stop(); };
        button2.MouseLeave += (s, o) => { timer.Stop(); };
        // popup event
        popup.MouseMove += (s, o) =>
        {
            // if outside of popup grid region - close
            if (!new Rect(grid.RenderSize).Contains(o.GetPosition(grid)))
                popup.IsOpen = false;
        };
        // clicks
        button1.Click += (s, o) => Title += "1";
        button2.Click += (s, o) => Title += "2";
        button3.Click += (s, o) => Title += "3";
        this.MouseDown += (s, o) => { Title += "w"; o.Handled = true; };
        panel.MouseDown += (s, o) => { Title += "p"; o.Handled = true; };
        grid.MouseDown += (s, o) => { Title += "g"; o.Handled = true; };
    }
}
```

Popup will appears after hovering button and disappears after moving mouse out of popup area.

If popup button clicking is timed correctly (right when popup appears), there are 2 possible issues:

- no popup button click event occurs (while popup is visible and button *seems to be clicked*), it's *swallowed* by something;
- popup will not get mouse captured (it will stay on screen until gets focus somehow, by clicking popup button to example), see picture:

[image]

Any ideas of what is going on and what to do to receive reliably popup button clicks?

Comment: how long is the delay?

Comment: @user1666620, `500 ms`, can be seen in posted code.

Comment: sorry, meant how long is the delay between the popup appearing and button clicks being registered.

Comment: @user1666620, try yourself (click as soon as it appears). I could measure delay precisely of course, but the tolerance seems quite big. I can easily reproduce the problem after just few clicks.